# how to redirect/map to externalregistration page from AuthenticateExternalAsync to angular page

Tags: identityserver3

I am using external providers to login to my web app. (for example Google). In my custom userservice I get to  AuthenticateExternalAsync and from there I want (if need to) redirect to Angular page.

```
   public override Task AuthenticateExternalAsync(ExternalAuthenticationContext context)
        {
        ...
        ...
         context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("~/externalregistration", user.Subject, name, identityProvider: user.Provider);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

i have html page
at https://localhost:44300/Content/app/externalregistration.html

How do I map externalregistration to this page?

At the moment I get an error 
https://localhost:44300/identity/externalregistration#
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

thank you
Mark

Answer (score 0):

The page for the partial login has to be with IdentityServer - see that it's looking for it at /identity/ and not /Content/app/.

Comment: every other page (such as index, login, logout, permissions etc...) are being picked up from that folder, i am missing something where the mapping is done from "identity/externalregistration" to my html page. in asp.net example it is done by use of attribute on a method, but I want to map to angular html page and this is where I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

If from your user service you issue a partial login, then that web page is entirely up to you to serve up from the server. If that partial login page needs to know the identity of the user, then it needs to be hosted in the same path as IdentityServer so the partial login cookie can be read on the server. If you then want that page to be a SPA, then you'd have to have some server side code issue something into the browser for your SPA to know the identity of the user. If you want that page to be a SPA and make Ajax calls back to the server, you need to include some XSRF protection.

All in all, custom partial pages are easiest implemented as standard server-rendered MVC pages.

Comment: ok, understand. I will go with MVC option as in your example.  Thank you